# Webpack build exposes source files, shouldn't be only uglyfied files?

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-dev-server

In Chrome Dev Tools, I can see my source files of build app. I'd expect it only for dev-server execution and webpack not giving away plain source files in build process.

Screenshot below is build and uploaded to server app, not my local machine.
[image: Webpack exposed source files]

This example app is from [Angular 2 official docs Webpack](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html). Is this expected behavior, if so how can I not give away my source files?

Comment: Did you build in production mode? And why do you care if the source files are available (uglification and minification can be largely undone, so that's not much to rely on)?

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes I did build in production mode, but as robertklep pointed out, it had source map files generated as well and I've just copied over distribution folder to server without cleaning those out. While you are right about those not being real inspection stopper, in case of a large app, all files uglified and bundled in one would be daunting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is based on the contents of the source map.

If you're using the [production configuration](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html#!#production-configuration), a separate source map file will be generated alongside your bundled resources (because of the `devtool : 'source-map'` option).

You can either remove the `devtool` option entirely for production mode, or just not upload the source map to the final destination on your server, if you don't want this.